# Error in Grouped regression using map function

Tags: r, regression

Grouped regression is running well model1 with "do".  But recently, it is told that do is superseded and suggested to use "across" but no example is given in the help file.  Model2 is given in "do" help, and it is running well without "map" or "across".  I don't understand how the regression is looping over those groups without map.  When I tried using map in model3, I am getting errors.  Model4 is given in Hadley's book, R for data science using split and working well. How to tell map function to consider the list "data". Any suggestions?

```r
library(purrr)
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
model1 = mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))
model1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     cyl mod   
#>   <dbl> <list>
#> 1     4 <lm>  
#> 2     6 <lm>  
#> 3     8 <lm>

## from "do" help file 
model2 = mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ disp, data = data)))
model2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl                data mod   
#>   <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,10]>> <list>
#> 1     4           [11 x 10] <lm>  
#> 2     6            [7 x 10] <lm>  
#> 3     8           [14 x 10] <lm>

## using map
model3 = mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fit`.
#> x numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
#> i Input `fit` is `map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))`.
#> i The error occured in row 1.

##model4
model4 = mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))
model4
#> $`4`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp  
#>     40.8720      -0.1351  
#> 
#> 
#> $`6`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp  
#>   19.081987     0.003605  
#> 
#> 
#> $`8`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp  
#>    22.03280     -0.01963
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an issue with `rowwise` attribute, we could `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>% 
     nest_by(cyl) %>% # // creates the rowwise attribute
     ungroup %>% # // remove the rowwise
     mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl                data fit   
#  <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,10]>> <list>
#1     4           [11 × 10] <lm>  
#2     6            [7 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8           [14 × 10] <lm>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But can you provide more explanation for why model2 is working and model4 is not working. How do we know that ungroup should be used? It is not intuitive.  Also, how model2 is working without looping?

Comment: @RamakrishnaS `model4` is splitting into a `list` and there is no grouping attribute.  If you do the same `mtcars %>% group_split(cyl) %>% map(~ lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))`  I guess you meant `model3` instead of `model4`?

Comment: Yes, I mean model3.  Please explain, why should `ungroup` is used.  I am not getting it right. Also, in model2 why `lm` should be enclosed in list().

Comment: @RamakrishnaS in `model2`, you are enclosing `lm` in a `list` because the model object is not a regular object.  It is a list of lot of components (please check the `str`) and if you don't wrap it in a list, it cannot be self-contained.  The reason is that `nest_by` is adding an extra attribute `rowwise`, while `group_by` `nest` doesn't i.e. `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest %>% mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .)))` works

Comment: @RamakrishnaS regarding why it is behaving differently in `nest_by`, the attribute added may be a bug and it could get corrected in the next release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219095/discussion-between-ramakrishna-s-and-akrun).